# setTimeout and setInterval not working in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

In Firefox OS setTimeout and setInterval method does not support for Firefox OS content security policy ( https://developer.mozilla.org/Apps/CSP ). But if i want to use this type of method then what will be the process instead of this method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Dynamic code execution with setTimeout and setInterval is banned"

"You MUST pass callable objects (i.e.: functions) to the setTimeout and setInterval functions. Passing strings will not create the timer and the function will return 0."

It doesn't disallow `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. It only bans passing strings to them, ie the following won't work

```
setTimeout('x = 5', 500);
```

but this will still work

```
setTimeout(function() { x = 5; }, 500);
```

Seriously, who would ban that?

Comment: This is a very good idea, if this dynamic code were allowed all kinds of crapware could be added without an ability to verify the integrity of the code, in fact every other similar API (android, ios) has something similar.